# Two ForEach in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I would like to make two loop in SwiftUI. For example :

```
ForEach (chapterData) { chapter in

  ForEach (chapter.line) { line in 

     Text("\(line.text)")
  }
}
```

the chapterData is an table of Chapter ( [Chapter] ) :

```
struct Chapter: Codable, Identifiable { 
  let id:Int
  let line:[Line] 
}
```

and

```
struct Line: Codable, Identifiable {
  let id: Int
  let text: String 
}
```

I would like to get the line.text of all chapters in chapterData

but I can't compile this code and I think it's not possible to do two ForEach Loops in this way.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Yes, I just added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed your Chapter - it's best to use plural names for any `Collection` as it improves readability of your code:

```
struct Chapter: Codable, Identifiable {
  let id:Int
  let lines: [Line]
}
```

There is a problem with your ForEach syntax and your second ForEach should take chapter.lines as its argument as this is the actual list. It's also important to wrap your outer ForEach in a `VStack` or `List`. So your views body could look like this:

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(chapterData) { chapter in
                ForEach(chapter.lines) { line in
                    Text(line.text)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```